# AutoCAD - accoreconsole.exe won't exit after executing the script file

Tags: c#, .net, autocad, autocad-plugin, autocad-scripts

We created a tool which depends on AutoCAD's `accoreconsole.exe` to batch process AutoCAD drawing files. We have the processing logic in a .NET DLL that will be `NETLOAD` from the script (`.scr`) file. It was working fine for the past 1.5 years, but recently after a windows update the `accoreconsole.exe` won't exit after processing the drawing file. The drawing file is processed as expected. But since the accoreconsole process doesn't exit, it causes our tool to freeze forever.

I could provide a workaround for this by killing the process after a timeout. But it would be better to identify the root cause of the problem and fix it. I couldn't find any valid solution online. I would appreciate your inputs to fix this problem. Thank you.

Our tool runs in Windows Server 2019 which has AutoCAD 2018 installed.
The following command is used to run accoreconsole:

`accoreconsole.exe /i <dwg_abs_path> /s <script_abs_path>`

Script file content -

```
;Loading the .NET module
(command "_.Netload" <dll_abs_path>)

; Run the command
(command <process_command_with_args>)
```